# Changing wordPress fonts file link

Tags: wordpress

I have recently migrated my WordPress site to the 'root' folder from a folder called 'dev'. Since then there is a console error and fonts in IOS devices are different. I did a global search but I couldn't find a code to change fonts links. This is the error in the console.

```
https://--Site Name--/public_html/dev/wp-content/fonts/roboto/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-AMP6lQ.woff
```

This should change to the

```
https://--Site Name--/public_html/dev/wp-content/fonts/roboto/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-AMP6lQ.woff
```

Comment: How did you put this font in `wp-content`directory? Do you use a plugin for that? Perhaps is it in its settings because there is no directory called fonts at this place on default WP installation.

Comment: I thinks its the theme settings

Comment: did you try to load another font in your theme so?

Comment: It worked when this on the dev folder. After the migration its stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for any plugin that can conflicts with fonts. Then check the database for the link. Change the link from there and you are good to go.